# How can I tell if my ISP is intentionally degrading service of particular websites (eg video)

Tags: networking, internet, youtube, isp

Some particular websites (youtube is a commonly cited example) frequently have poor streaming performance. How can I determine if youtube is just not good at doing video, or if my ISP is just intentionally degrading services of their choosing.

Comment: You can try using a VPN service.  Of course that comes with its own potential bottleknecks.